# String to Map Conversion Hive

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, hive

I have a table having four columns.

```
C1    C2    C3    C4
--------------------
x1    y1    z1    d1
x2    y2    z2    d2
```

Now I want convert it into map data type having key and value pairs and load into separate table.

```
create table test
(
   level map<string,string>
)
row format delimited
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '&'
map keys terminated by '=';
```

Now I am using below sql to load data.

```
insert overwrite table test
select str_to_map(concat('level1=',c1,'&','level2=',c2,'&','level3=',c3,'&','level4=',c4) from input;
```

Select query on the table.

```
select * from test;
{"level1":"x1","level2":"y1","level3":"z1","level4":"d1=\\"}
{"level1":"x2","level2":"y2","level3":"z2","level4":"d2=\\"}
```

I didn't get why I am getting extra "=\ \" in last value.

I double check data but the issue persist.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`str_to_map(text, delimiter1, delimiter2)` - Creates a map by parsing text 
Split text into key-value pairs using two delimiters. The first delimiter seperates pairs, and the second delimiter sperates key and value. If only one parameter is given, default delimiters are used: `','` as `delimiter1` and `'='` as `delimiter2`.

You can get this info by running this command:

```
describe function extended str_to_map
```

In your syntax there are two errors:

```
insert overwrite table test
select str_to_map(concat('level1=',c1,'&','level2=',c2,'&','level3=',c3,'&','level4=',c4) from input;
```

First is, one bracket **)** is missing.

Second is, its not an error basically, you have not given the delimiters so the function is taking default values for delimiters, That's why your are getting **','** in your result.

To get the output in current format you should try this query:

```
insert overwrite table test
select str_to_map(concat('level1=',c1,'&','level2=',c2,'&','level3=',c3,'&','level4=',c4),'&','=') from input;
```

Comment: Note well that `delimiter1` and `delimiter2` are passed to `split` which means they'll be interpreted as regular expressions!