# Convert SparkSQL output to a (K,V) pair using str_to_map()

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I query for few columns from hive table and want to convert the sql ouput into a rdd. I want to use that rdd to convert the rows(in the RDD output) into key,value pairs. I tried to tweak [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023068/string-to-map-conversion-hive) query like

**scala> select str_to_map(df.rdd.collect(),'\n',',') from my_hive_table;**

But I could'nt. Is this possible. If yes,then how?

Comment: Have you looked at the Spark documentation? http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

Comment: Yes.I did. :) But couldnt find anything on embedding collecting data as (K,V) pair inside a SparkSQLQuery.

Comment: `select str_to_map(df.rdd.collect(),'\n',',') from my_hive_table;` is not Scala. And hence it will not work in Scala-REPL.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh It wouldn't work in Spark even if syntax was correct.

Comment: @zero323 correct syntax of which language ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh My point is that is not (only) about syntax. One could wrap it with with `SQLContext.sql` and it wouldn't be correct either. A whole idea here looks like XY-problem to be fair.